# MVC 4 Razor - Creating a dynamic DropDownList

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to create a view which has two DropDownLists. The options available in the second DropDownList depend upon what the user has selected in the first. I'm passing this data to my view in the ViewBag as follows:

```
   List<SelectListItem> firstBoxChoices =  ViewBag.firstBoxChoices;
   Dictionary<string, List<SelectListItem>> secondBoxDict = ViewBag.secondBoxDict;
```

The first object has the choices for the first DropDownList. When the user selects one of those, I need to get the appropriate list of choices for the second DropDownList from my Dictionary. I just can't figure out how to achieve this. If I get the new selection of the first DropDownList in a Javascript onchange() function, there doesn't seem to be any way to use this value as the key for my C# dictionary.

Of course, I've seen this functionality on the web so I know it must be possible somehow. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple ways of doing this without forcing you to store all the possible data items in the model, my preference is to use Javascript/JQuery.  Here is an example of a Country/State cascading drop down:

Javascript used to get states when a country is selected:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AppendUrlParamTokens(url, params) {

        for (var param in params) {
            if (params[param] == null) {
                delete params[param];
            }
        }

        return url + "?" + jQuery.param(params);
    }

    function OnCountriesChange(ddl) {
        jQuery.getJSON(AppendUrlParamTokens('@Url.Action("GetStates", "Data")', { countryId: ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value }), function (result) {
            var target = jQuery('#states_ddl');
            target.empty();
            jQuery(result).each(function() {
                jQuery(document.createElement('option'))
                    .attr('value', this.Value)
                    .text(this.Text)
                    .appendTo(target);
            });
        });
    };
</script>
```

Country dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "Value", "Text", Model.PreviousCountrySelected), "(Select One)", new { id = "countries_ddl", onchange = "OnCountriesChange(this)" })
```

State dropdown:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State,
                              Model.States != null
                                       ? new SelectList(Model.States, "Value", "Text", Model.PreviousStateSelected)
                                       : new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>(), "Value", "Text"),
                              new { id = "states_ddl" })
```

Controller method to retrieve states:

```
public ActionResult GetStates(short? countryId)
{
    if (!countryId.HasValue)
    {
        return Json(new List<object>(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    var data = GetAllStatesForCountry(countryId.Value).Select(o => new { Text = o.StateName, Value = o.StateId });

    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The idea is that on selection of dropdown 1 you use ajax to go retrieve your second dropdown's value.

**Edit:** Forgot to include utility method for constructing urls

Answer (score 4):

The `.change` event of your first select should populate the second select by calling a server method that returns the option data based on the selected value. Given the following view model

```
public class MyModel
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select an organisation")]
  [Display(Name = "Organisation")]
  public int? SelectedOrganisation { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select an employee")]
  [Display(Name = "Employee")]
  public int? SelectedEmployee { get; set; }
  public SelectList OrganisationList { get; set; }
  public SelectList EmployeeList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int ID)
{
  MyModel model = new MyModel();
  model.SelectedOrganisation = someValue; // set if appropriate
  model.SelectedEmployee = someValue; // set if appropriate
  ConfigureEditModel(model); // populate select lists
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyModel model)
{
  if(!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ConfigureEditModel(model); // reassign select lists
    return View(model);
  }
  // save and redirect
}

private void ConfigureEditModel(MyModel model)
{
  // populate select lists
  model.OrganisationList = new SelectList(db.Organisations, "ID", "Name");
  if(model.SelectedOrganisation.HasValue)
  {
    var employees = db.Employees.Where(e => e.Organisation == model.SelectedOrganisation.Value);
    model.EmployeeList = new SelectList(employees, "ID", 
  }
  else
  {
    model.EmployeeList = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>());
  }
}

[HttpGet]
public JsonResult FetchEmployees(int ID)
{
  var employees = db.Employees.Where(e => e.Organisation == ID).Select(e => new
  {
    ID = e.ID,
    Name = e.Name
  });
  return Json(employees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

View

```
@model MyModel
....
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedOrganisation)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedOrganisation, Model.OrganisationList, "-Please select-")
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedOrganisation)
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedEmployee)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedEmployee, Model.EmployeeList, "-Please select-")
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedEmployee)
....
```

Script

```
var url = '@Url.Action("FetchEmployees")';
var employees = $('SelectedEmployee');
$('#SelectedOrganisation').change(function() {
  employees.empty();
  if(!$(this).val()) {
    return;
  }
  employees.append($('<option></option>').val('').text('-Please select-'));
  $.getJson(url, { ID: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
      employees.append($('<option></option>').val(item.ID).text(item.Text));
    });
  });
});
```