# Best approach to show a DropdownList depending on a condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

I have one view with 2 dropdowlist, one of them will be displayed depending on the value of the other. The model of my view is a List of Models(all the same) if I select one option from the first dropdownlist(this one displays the Name property of all models), then, I will render the second one(dropdownlist) depending on a property of the selected model.
Can you please let me know which is the best approach. Also I need a few examples of how will look the view and the code behind of my Controller.

```
MyModel{
string Name{get;set;}
List<string> Options{get;set;}
}
```

Selecting mymodelInstance.Name from the first dropdown, I will check if Options.Count has a 0 value and I don't wont to render the dropdown that belong to Options

Comment: You question is not clear, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117094/mvc-4-razor-creating-a-dynamic-dropdownlist/28122962#28122962)  gives an example of creating a cascading dropdown's

Answer (score 3):

I would use javascript for that. If not, you'll have to redraw the page to get the values for the second dropdownlist. You need to handle the change event on the first dropdownlist and make an AJAX request to get the items of the second dropdownlist.